# Iframe and parent page both being tracked by GA

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

We have a page used for ads that feature an iframe of a form (all on the same domain). The page and the iframe are both being tracked in analytics, but we only want the main page to be tracked. Our analytics are not accurate due to this and I am trying to turn off tracking for the iframe page. I just want the parent page to be tracked and not the page that is in an iframe on the parent page.

Have tried setting up a filter on GA but that had the opposite effect we needed.

Comment: remove the tracking code from the page loaded in through iframe.

Comment: If I remove the tracking code it will remove it on all pages as the code is placed in the header. Is there another way to remove it just from that page? @XTOTHEL

Comment: You can set it just in GTM. Give me please some URL of your iframe form as example (without hostname).

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution would be to check if the current page sits in an iframe and, if so, use an exception trigger on your Google Analytics tags.

E.g. you could create a custom javascript variable "isIframe":

```
function() {
   return window.location !== window.parent.location;
}
```

If this returns true, you are inside the iframe.

Then you create trigger of the "custom event" type, enable regex matching and put in ".*" in the event name (so this catches all events). Select "fires on some events" and set "isIframe equals true" as condition. Attach this as an exception trigger to your GA tracking tag(s).

Now if your GTM instance runs inside the iframe the tracking is blocked (so the iframe will not be counted as a pageview), but the tracking for the host page will still work.